# WPF Binding GridView to Element in collection

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm, binding

I'm creating a form that will allows user to add filters to data for processing.

I have setup:

```
public Class RuleGroup
{
   public ObservableCollection<Rule> Rules {get; set;}
   ...
}

public Class Rule
{
   public ObservableCollection<String> Fields {get; set;}
   public ObservableCollection<Rule> Rules {get; set;}
   ...
}

public class Criteria
{
     public int ItemId{ get; set;}
     public string Field{ get; set;}
     public OperationType Operation{ get; set;}
     public string Value {get; set;}
     public string Value2 {get; set;}
}
```

So a Rule has a List of Criteria that must be matched if the rule is to be applied. Each Criteria in a Rule must specify a value for every field selected. The Amount of fields may vary from One RuleGroup to the next.

I am trying to set up a form that is user friendly when creating multiple Rules. I was thinking of having a GridView on the form that is some how bound to this class layout.

Rule = Row
Criteria = Column

Currently I have function that generates a DataTable based on the Rules/Criteria as the user move from one RuleGroup to the next, but I think there my be an nicer solution to this

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Think I have got it.

Needed to change my Classes around a bit to get the correct groups / hierarchy. I have then been able to bind the column using the items index in the collection.

This has given me the outcome I wanted, Though there is a minor issue where I would like to be able to access the index using the string Name rather then the position. I am currently having to make sure that the "Criterion" are in the correct order when accessing the values.

Here is a link to the [Source code](http://sdrv.ms/1dR3ufS)

**Rule Group**

```
public class RuleGroup
{
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Rule> Rules { get; set; }

    public RuleGroup()
    {
        Rules = new ObservableCollection<Rule>();
    }
}
```

**Rule**

```
public class Rule
{
    public Rule()
    {
        Criteria = new ObservableCollection<Criteria>();
    }

    public String Description { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Criteria> Criteria { get; set; }

    readonly ObservableCollection<RuleField> _Fields = new ObservableCollection<RuleField>();
    public IEnumerable<RuleField> Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return _Fields;
        }

    }

    public void AddField(string name, string header)
    {
        if (_Fields.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == name) == null)
        {
            RuleField field = new RuleField(_Fields.Count)
            {
                Name = name,
                Header = header
            };

            _Fields.Add(field);

            AddFieldToCriteria(field);

        }

    }

    void AddFieldToCriteria(RuleField field)
    {
        foreach (Criteria c in Criteria)
        {
            if (c.Values.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Field == field) == null)
                c.Values.Add(new Criterion() { Field = field, Operation = 1 });
        }
    }
}
```

**Criteria**

```
public class Criteria
{
    public Criteria()
    {
        Values = new ObservableCollection<Criterion>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Criterion> Values { get; set; }

    public Criterion this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Values.OrderBy(i=>i.Field.Position).ElementAt(index);
        }
        set
        {
            Criterion c = Values.OrderBy(i => i.Field.Position).ElementAt(index);
            c= value;
        }
    }

}
```

**Criterion**

```
public class Criterion
{
    public RuleField Field { get; set; }
    public int Operation { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

**RuleField**

```
public class RuleField
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }

    int _Position = 0;

    public int Position
    {
        get
        {
            return _Position;
        }
    }

    public RuleField(int position)
    {
        _Position = position;
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public delegate void UpdateColumnsEventHandler(object sender, UpdateColumnsEventArgs e);

public class UpdateColumnsEventArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<RuleField> Columns { get; set; }

    public UpdateColumnsEventArgs()
    {
        Columns = new List<RuleField>();
    }

    public UpdateColumnsEventArgs(IEnumerable<RuleField> columns)
    {
        Columns = columns;
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public event UpdateColumnsEventHandler UpdateColumns;

    public ObservableCollection<RuleGroup> RuleGroups { get; set; }

    RuleGroup _SelectedRuleGroup = null;
    public RuleGroup SelectedRuleGroup
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedRuleGroup;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedRuleGroup == value)
                return;

            _SelectedRuleGroup = value;

        }
    }

    public Rule _SelectedRule = null;
    public Rule SelectedRule
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedRule;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedRule == value)
                return;

            _SelectedRule = value;

            if (UpdateColumns != null)
                UpdateColumns(this, new UpdateColumnsEventArgs(_SelectedRule.Fields));
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        RuleGroups = new ObservableCollection<RuleGroup>();

        RuleGroup rg = new RuleGroup();
        rg.Description = "Rule Group A";

        Rule r = new Rule();
        r.Description = "Rule 1";

        Random random = new Random();
        int range = 10000;

        for (int x = 0; x < 2000; x++)
        {
            Criteria c = new Criteria();
            c.Values.Add(new Criterion()
            {
                Field = new RuleField(0)
                {
                    Name = "A",
                    Header = "A Column"
                },
                Operation = 1,
                Value = "X"
            });

            c.Values.Add(new Criterion()
            {
                Field = new RuleField(0)
                {
                    Name = "B",
                    Header = "B Column"
                },
                Operation = 1,
                Value = x % 10
            });

            r.Criteria.Add(c);
        }

        #region Fields

        r.AddField("A", "A Column");
        r.AddField("B", "B Column");
        r.AddField("C", "C Column");

        #endregion

        rg.Rules.Add(r);

        r = new Rule();
        r.Description = "Rule 2";

        for (int x = 0; x < 1750; x++)
        {
            r.Criteria.Add(new Criteria());
        }

        #region Fields

        r.AddField("A", "A Column");
        r.AddField("B", "B Column");

        #endregion

        rg.Rules.Add(r);

        RuleGroups.Add(rg);
    }
}
```

**WPF Window**

```
<Window x:Class="RuleMappingTest.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:RuleMappingTest"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel UpdateColumns="UpdateGridColumns"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding RuleGroups}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRuleGroup}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRuleGroup.Rules}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRule}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <DataGrid x:Name="CriteriaGrid" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedRule.Criteria}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**WPF Code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void UpdateGridColumns(object sender, UpdateColumnsEventArgs e)
    {
        CriteriaGrid.Columns.Clear();
        foreach (RuleField rf in e.Columns)
        {
            DataGridTextColumn c = new DataGridTextColumn();
            c.Header = rf.Header;
            Binding b = new Binding(String.Format("[{0}].Value", rf.Position));
            CriteriaGrid.Columns.Add(c);
            c.Binding = b;
        }
    }
}
```